# Table 1 record should not be present in Table 2

Tags: php, mysql, sql, subquery, left-join

I have two tables in the same database in **mysql**:

1. Table 1
2. Table 2

I am using phpmyadmin and php.

I have the column 'teamid' in both the tables and table 1 contains several different events columns.
So I have pulled out teamid who are participating in particular events from table1.

I also have column teamid in table2 who have participated in particular events. So I have also pulled out teamid who are participating in particular events from table2.

Query 1: **Select teamid From `table1` where event1pay='Paid'**
Query 2: **Select teamid From `table2` where event='event1'**

So from Query 1 and Query 2, I pulled out teamid.

Table1: it has 55 records

Table2: it has 5 records.

I want table1 teamid records should not be present in table2 teamid records.

The required query should return 50 records.

I have applied Left Join, NOT IN but it is not working as both the above queries have different where clause.

Comment: So, what problem are you having? There isn't enough code to help you here or how it's failing you.

Comment: have you try `on table1.teamid  != table2.teamid` ?

Comment: please show the query you tried and explain how it failed.

Comment: Column teamid is there in both tables. I want table1 teamid records should not be present in table2 column teamid.
there are many events in table 1 I am pulling out teamid from table 1 who are participated and paid for the respective event. Table2 has teams who has only participated in respective events. So I just want table1 teamid column records should not be there in table2 teamid column

Comment: Why not amend the problem such that t1 has 10 records, and t2 has 2 records, and see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend `not exists`:

```
select *
from table1 t1
where  event1pay = 'Paid' and not exists (
    select 1 
    from table2 t2 
    where t2.event = 'event1' and t2.teamid = t1.teamid
)
```

If you want to do this with an anti-`left join`, that would be:

```
select t1.*
from table1 t1
left join table2 t2 on t2.teamid = t1.teamid and t2.event = 'event1'
where t1.event1pay = 'Paid' and t2.teamid is null
```

But I find that `not exists` is a better way to express what you want to do here.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! This is the query that I was looking for. I have checked with the database and I am getting the desired output. Thank you once again.
I have checked with the not exists query and its working well.

Comment: @RahulSahu if solution worked for you then you should accept it as answer instead of leaving a comment.